# osx terminal syntax emulation on windows for node scripts

Tags: windows, macos, terminal, terminal-emulator

So I have a package json file that was built with osx in mind and it contains scripts for installs and builds. A lot of the scripts in that file have osx terminal specific syntax. Is there a way to emulate that terminal in windows so that syntax is read properly?

P.S. I've tried cygwin mintty (now called cygwin64 terminal), but still have the same issues.

**EDIT** My intention is not to maintain two files that essentially do the same thing and because we started off only using npm package manager I really don't want to introduce a task runner at this point.

**EDIT 9/15/15**
Here's an example of cygwin not emulating syntax:
`NODE_ENV=production bin/build.sh` in linux (ubuntu) will assign "production" to the node_env var and then execute the shell file build.sh, but in windows this syntax will cause errors with the var assignment and with the execution of the shell script file unless I use this syntax: `setx NODE_ENV production&&bash bin/build.sh`

Comment: well, what didn't work with cygwin and why?

Comment: I guess it would be better to post specific the problem you have while executing with Cygwin.

Comment: checkout my new edit to the op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X is based on BSD, so the closest approximation would be using a [BSD VM](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html).

Comment: unfortunately, adding a VM OS just to run npm commands would be way to much at this point, but I will be looking into that bsd for another project. thanks

Comment: after much searching this seems to be the only way to achieve this. so I used virtualbox and ubuntu and have shifted my dev environment to this VM. I think I'll look into adding linux as a new partition on my machine to be used for programming and development.